# Expected value and variance of max{x, y}

Tags: probability, dice

I've run into this problem while playing a game called Europa Universalis 4. I've done similar maths before in my studies so I'm pretty sure this should have an easy answer but I can't for the life of me remember how to do it.

In this game there are monarchs. Each monarch has 3 stats each determined by 2d4 - 2 die rolls. That's rolling two dice ranging 1-4 and subtracting 2 from the result, giving non-uniform distribution from 0 to 6. For simplicity I just count all 3 stats up as equals, so that makes 6d4 - 6 for their total stat, ranging 0 to 18 or in mathematical terms, I suppose this would be
$$
Monarch Points = -6 + \sum_1^6 Xi
$$
$$
Xi = Uniformly Discretely(1,4)
$$

The problem is as follows: I am comparing Government form A, where I get a randomly generated monarch from the method above, to Government B, where I get **two** randomly generated monarchs from the method above and pick the best one. Obviously, government B is better, but by how much? To get a meaningful answer I'm trying to compare the expected value and variances, but I'm pulling a complete blank here.

Comment: You're looking for the expected values and variances of what exactly? Of "Monarch points" and "max(Monarch points 1, Monarch points 2)"? Do you know how to compute the expected value of "Monarch points"?

Comment: Correct, I am looking for the expected values and variances of MonarchPoints and max{MonarchPoints1, MonarchPoints2). The expected value of MonarchPoints, unless I'm gravely mistaken, is just -6 + 6*E[X] = 9. The variance of MonarchPoints I believe is 6 * (5*3)/12 = 7.5 since the die rolls are uncorrelated. Then I am completely stuck on the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may answer this via brute force; it's simple since your variables are discrete and independent.

I'm going to answer a slightly simpler question.  Consider the sum of two 4-sided dice.  Probability for discrete variables is the outcome divided by the number of events in the sample space.  Thus you get:

Let X be the sum of two 4 sided dice; then there are 8 - 1 = 7 outcomes, with probs (recall there are 16 = 4*4 events in the sample space)

```
P(X = 2) = 1/16 = {(1,1)}
P(X = 3) = 2/16 = {(1,2), (2,1)}
P(X = 4) = 3/16 = {(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)}
P(X = 5) = 4/16 = {(1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1)}
P(X = 6) = 3/16 = {(2,4), (3,3), (4,2)}
P(X = 7) = 2/16 = {(3,4), (4,3)}
P(X = 8) = 1/16 = {(4,4)}
```

so E is the sum of x * P(x) for all x in the sample space, ie:

{2*1 + 3*2 + 4*3 + 5*4 + 6*3 + 7*2 + 8*1}/16 = 5

and the variance is similarly defined.

Now, to your question, we can simply brute force the answer.  Here's some R code:

```
# note the na in P(1) to make indexing easier
probs <- c(NA,1,2,3,4,3,2,1)/16

# E of single var
E <- 0
for( x in 2:8)
    E <- E + x * probs[x]
print(sprintf('E is %f', E))

# E of max of 2 vars
E <- 0
for(x in 2:8){
    for(y in 2:8){
        E <- E + max(x,y) * probs[x] * probs[y]
    }
}
print(sprintf('E of max is %f', E))
```

ie the expectation is 5.890625 so 0.89 better.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more mathematical answer: if you have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, one way to begin analyzing $Z \equiv \max \{ X,Y \}$ is to compute its CDF:

$$F_Z(z) = \mathbb{P} \left ( \left \{ \omega \in \Omega : \max \{ X(\omega),Y(\omega) \} \leq z \right \} \right ) \\
= \mathbb{P} \left ( \left \{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq z \land Y(\omega) \leq z \right \} \right ) \\
= F_X(z) F_Y(z) $$

where the last line uses the independence. In this problem this is a bit messy because $F_X$ jumps at $24-5=19$ different points, but it is still doable, albeit easier with a computer.

Comment: To make it simpler: $$F_Z(z)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)=F_X(x)^2$$

Comment: Technically I made a slightly more general remark about arbitrary independent $X$ and $Y$. In this particular case of course $F_Z(z) = F_X(z)^2$.